# How can I vary rsync's bandwidth usage without stopping the process?

Tags: 14.04, backup, rsync

I have been transferring large files recently to my server (running Ubuntu) with rsync. In order to stop it using all my bandwidth I have been using the `--bwlimit` option to throttle it. However, because of the size of these files, rsync sometimes runs for longer than a day and so I am looking for a way to vary its bandwidth usage whilst it's running so that it's lower during peak times and higher during the night. I realise I could use the `--partial` option and then stop it, change the `--bwlimit` value and start it again at various points during the day, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution available, maybe one that could respond to the actual amount of bandwidth available (I am probably hoping for too much here).

I am running a number of applications where bandwidth usage is a problem so if anyone has a suggestion for throttling bandwidth for linux processes in general that isn't rsync specific then that would be awesome as well.

Comment: You might want to consider searching for ways to do QoS either within Linux or within your home network environment.

Comment: I've not looked into this well enough to formulate a full answer but do know that `tc` and `wondershaper` can be used to control the traffic handling on specific interfaces. It's possible to use `cstream` as a stream handling tool, normally used on command line constructed pipes. All are available in the Ubuntu repositories.